# What's the name of a timer that fires if something *doesn't* happen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, debouncing

I want to find or build a React Hook that will run a callback function if something else stops happening. Examples: user stops scrolling, requests stop arriving, error stop happening, etc.

The implementation seems straightforward: start a timer for user-specified msecs, and return a function that increments the timer's expiration time by the same msecs.  When the timer fires, call the callback (if it's after expiration), otherwise restart the timer until the expiration time.

I'm sure this has been done before. Does this technique have a well-known name like "debouncing" and "thottling" have?  Are there library implementations?

Comment: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/promises-with-timeouts/

Comment: Honestly, this seems like debouncing with possibly a larger timeout. It's just that the thing you're debouncing needs to regularly call your debounced function. So if you have some sort of `onError` that gets called, then you debounce it with a timeout of, say, 5 seconds and if 5 seconds pass between errors, you consider that "errors have stopped" and the debounced function fires. Correct me if I'm wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: Well, that action times out. I don't think there is yet a name for it.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, what OP is describing is exactly what "debouncing" is.

Comment: @VLAZ - You're totally right!  I had always thought of debouncing as being something that was used with small timeouts to reduce chattiness during a long operation, but with long timeouts I think you're correct that it will do exactly what I'm looking for. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

i've generally called these kind of event listeners "heartbeats" or "countdown timers"

Comment: A heartbeat is usually different - a regular check with something.

Comment: agreed, but a heartbeat usually implies that an action will be done if the heartbeat does not succeed for a given interval. I imagine this is close in spirit to what the OP was asking for.